# Dex error I can't seem to fix after adding a library

Tags: android, dex

I just added a new Gradle library to my app, or rather said to two apps. In one app, it worked flawlessly, in the second I am getting weird DEX errors.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow;

I already checked out the library, there is no IntelliJ or annotation dependency.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.droidtitan.lintcleaner'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'README.md'
    exclude 'Other/'
    exclude 'keystore.jks'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fa.daily"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 290
    versionName "@string/version"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty("KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
            storeFile file(KEYSTORE_PATH)
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    gplay {
        applicationId 'com.fa.daily.free'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

}

repositories {
maven {
    url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
}
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//wearApp project(':wear')\n' +
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.4.0'
gplayCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.6'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:+'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:+'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:android-flipview:+'

compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.jenzz:materialpreference:1.3'

compile 'com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity:0.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'

compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'

compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:10.2.6'

compile 'com.github.igalata:Bubble-Picker:v0.2.4'
compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.1.5'

compile 'com.gjiazhe:PanoramaImageView:1.0'

compile 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:1.1'

compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'

compile 'com.github.clockbyte:admobadapter:1.4.1'

compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: might be you are configuring same library two times, check for that.

Comment: paste your app level gradle file

Comment: @ifiok done....

Comment: which jars fo you have in your lib folder?

Comment: @ifiok only Jsoup.